# Case fan that works with the motherboard controls

Tags: case

Im after a case fan that i can use with the motherboards controll. I currently have

Current configuration

- Coarsair carbide 100r silent edition http://www.corsair.com/en-au/carbide-series-100r-silent-edition-mid-tower-case
- Motherboard Gigabyte H170-H3D

The case fans are 3 pin and appear not to be compatible with the motherboard controlls

So far i've considered

- Noctua NF-S12A PWM 120mm 1200RPM Case Fan NF-S12APWM
- Corsair CO-9050040-WW ML120 Pro 120mm Premium Magnetic Levitation Fan
- Corsair CO-9050042-WW ML120 PRO LED Red 120mm Premium Magnetic Levitation Fan

But im not really sure here, does the magnetic levitation add anything? Is it a problem that the Noctua is a little slower on the total RPM.

Also there are alot of specs around fans such as static pressure and high air flow etc, how much does this matter

As for usage of the pc, does not have a graphic card, may get one one day, no overclocking.

**In essence**

- Want to replace fan with one that can be controlled through a 4 pin connector
- Would like it to be a bit quieter, color optional if does not comprimise the following too much

Comment: What do you mean by motherboard controls?  Are you talking about where the detected temperature determines what RPM the fans run at?    Also, are you sure the board isn't an HD3 or a D3H?  I am not finding anything for a H170-H3D.   Either way, your board should have a 4pin connection for the CPU cooler, and 3pin connections for case fans.  As long as the fans are PWM they can be controlled by the board  [see this article](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2205716/explain-3pin-4pin-fan-correctly.html)